# Swipe animation from left to right infinite time

Tags: android, alpha, translate-animation

I have an `imageview` in my `relativelayout`,my requirement is:

i want to swipe the `imageview` from left to right and fadeout, again from left,fadein swipe left to right and fade out

```
 ----                           ----
|    |   swipe left to right   |    |  Fade out here
|    |   --> ---> --->         |    |
|    |                         |    |
 ----                           ----
```

Fade in again from left and Repeat:

```
 ----                           ----
|    |   swipe left to right   |    |  Fade out here
|    |   --> ---> --->         |    |
|    |                         |    |
 ----                           ----
```

this question doesn't match any other question on stack,so don't try to flag it.

what i know is, i can use this:

This is for left to right animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

and for fade in and fade out effect:

```
fadein.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
          android:duration="2000"/>
     </set>
fadeout.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
          android:duration="2000"/>
     </set>
```

but the problem is how to relocate the imageview back at same position after fading it out from right to come back at left again and repeat.

Comment: I would think that you could do that programmatically, or maybe even by simply applying a new translation of -100% immediately after it has faded out to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an [Animation Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to both animations.

At `onAnimationEnd()` of the fade-out animation, set the visibility of the `ImageView` to `GONE`.  Then, start the fade-in animation and on `onAnimationStart()` for that one set the visibility of the `ImageView` to `VISIBLE`.

You don't need to set the position of the image at all, just let the animations do their thing.

*EDIT:*

Add a translate component to your animations in addition to the fade:

```
fadein.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
      android:duration="2000" />
     <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:duration="700" />
 </set>

fadeout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
      android:duration="2000"/>
     <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%" 
      android:duration="700"/>
 </set>
```